# How to run query generated by queries inside a select statement in aws athena

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

My goal is to reduce query length.

For each column I need to calculate ntile(). Query is as follows

```
Select col1, n_tile over(order by col1), 
col2, n_tile over(order by col2), ....
  From main_table
```

Here is my attempt.

```
With columns as(
    SELECT column_name 
      From information_schema.columns
     Where table_name='main_table'),
n_tile_funcs as (
    Select column_name, CONCAT('ntile(4) over (order by ', column_name, ' asc)') as ntilefunc 
      From columns),
 query_tbl as (
    Select CONCAT(ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_AGG(column_name), ',') ' ,' , ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_AGG(ntilefunc), ','))
      From n_tile_funcs)
```

This successfully creates what must be ran inside select statement however I cannot figure out a way to use above result as select statement. For example

```
Select (select query from query_tbl)
  From main_table
```

This simply outputs query string for number of rows in main_table.

How to run query made from queries inside a select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute a dynamic query in the same query that generated it, full stop.

SQL requires that a given statement be complete at the time it is parsed, which is before it begins reading any values or evaluating expressions. This means all syntax and identifiers must be explicit and fixed.

If you need to generate a new query, you must store it in a variable and use dynamic SQL to prepare and execute it as a second action.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I store query as a variable when I execute query, the engine is going to fill variable with actual query string then execute, correct? Therefore my initial goal of reducing query length is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean you want to reduce the query _time_? I don't understand why reducing the length of the string that holds the query is important.

Comment: Because there is query length limit in AWS Athena.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that Athena has that limit (it's 256KB according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html). You'll have to split up your query, as they recommend on that page.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there are any alternatives as I was too lazy to split up queries.

Comment: I haven't used AWS Athena, but I've read a bit about it, and I think it definitely fits the "implement 70% of the features, then release" philosophy shown by many other AWS products. Pretty disappointing.